# Auth0 Endpoint "api/auth/me" returns a 404 Error in Next.js App

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, auth0, auth0-connection

I have gone through the following [tutorial](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/nextjs?_ga=2.210244693.1956483687.1651804114-593144712.1651431454&_gac=1.219470315.1651573063.Cj0KCQjwpcOTBhCZARIsAEAYLuUsX_Kn2umgKqFdUl2Z_EvOpTAcbUaIVD4RPDAnRiScdkh4_HzCNgYaAne9EALw_wcB&_gl=1*1un926s*rollup_ga*NTkzMTQ0NzEyLjE2NTE0MzE0NTQ.*rollup_ga_F1G3E656YZ*MTY1MTg0OTYyOS4xMi4xLjE2NTE4NDk2MzAuNTk.) to get my Next.js App integrated with Auth0.
I am able to log in and log out just fine but when trying to display user information on the page after login, **the `user` object is unable to be returned**. I have ensured that there is nothing wrong with the Profile.js page that is rendering the `user` object or the env.local file with my app's secret keys.

After further inspection I noticed that I get an error in the browser console that reads: `Failed to Load Resource ... 404 Not Found: http://localhost:3000/api/auth/me`.

This error gives me a gut feeling that there is a discrepancy in the mapping between my next.js app and Auth0 since I have modified the basepath in next.config.js:

```js
module.exports = {
  basePath: '/my_path',

  webpack: (config) => {
    return config
  },

  env: {
  },

  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    BACKEND_API_URL: process.env.BACKEND_API_URL,
    CONSENT_COOKIE_NAME: 'ConsentCookie'
  },
}
```

Is there a way to add my basepath into the endpoint that the `user` object is being returned from? The end result would look something like: `https://localhost:3000/my_path/api/auth/me`

I am not 100% certain that this will fix my issue with getting the `user` object returned properly, so I am open to any other suggestions and willing to add more context surrounding specific files in my app.

---

Edit:
After bringing this issue up on the Auth0 forums ([link](https://community.auth0.com/t/http-localhost-3000-api-auth-me-returns-404-in-console/82831/6)), I was pointed towards this [link](https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0/blob/e70112ebff74993b7fd1c8194b8a66c418ac84ab/src/frontend/use-user.tsx#L184), which is another example Next.js Auth0 sample app, except they have written their frontend with TypeScript (which I am not familiar with). They are manipulating the `UserContext` object and resetting the ProfileURL, which is what I am after; so what would be the JavaScript equivalent to this?

The same repsonse to the Auth0 forum post I mentioned also included another [link](https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0/blob/625cf2e6d15ec65909d67459075c4057c08f8b19/EXAMPLES.md#use-custom-auth-urls) to an example function that creates a custom URL for the login. This is very close to what I am after since again, I am trying to create a custom auth URL to retrieve the `User` object and get rid of the `404 ... /api/auth/me not found` error.
Due to my inexperience with JS, my attempts at trying to create a similar function to the example stated previously have failed, so what would this look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am feeling intense bittersweet emotions after finding an insultingly simple solution to this issue.

Found in the [readme.md](https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0#base-path-and-internationalized-routing) of the NextJS-Auth0 repository...
This small snippet of code fixed all of my issues after hours of searching for a solution -

```js
// _app.js
function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <UserProvider loginUrl="/foo/api/auth/login" profileUrl="/foo/api/auth/me">
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </UserProvider>
  );
}
```

Now to get back to wiping the tears off my desk..

Comment: You don't need the additional props as long as your folders are setup correctly. At the top level you should have /pages/api/auth. Within the auth you create the dynamic [auth0].js/ts file which exposes the endpoints (including me) once you export the handler.

Answer (score 1):

I have been having this issue too. What was happening for my Next app deployed on Vercel is that all the `api/auth/*` routes were not working in production but everything worked locally.

I'm using the Auth0 Universal Login Experience

```json
// package.json
...
"dependencies": {
    "@auth0/nextjs-auth0": "^1.9.2",
}
...
```

All I had before was the function

```js
// api/auth/[...auth0].ts
import { handleAuth } from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0";

export default handleAuth();
```

So what I did is create all the paths I'd need in my application in their respective files. I think Next.js was not creating the dynamic files at `[...auth0].ts`

```js
// api/auth/callback.ts
import { handleCallback } from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0";
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

const callbackHandler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  try {
    await handleCallback(req, res);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(error.status || 400).end(error.message);
  }
};

export default callbackHandler;
```

```js
// api/auth/login.ts
import { handleLogin } from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0";
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

const loginHandler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  try {
    await handleLogin(req, res, {
      authorizationParams: {
        screen_hint: "login",
      },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(error.status || 400).end(error.message);
  }
};

export default loginHandler;
```

```js
// api/auth/logout.ts
import { handleLogout } from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0";
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

const logoutHandler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  try {
    await handleLogout(req, res);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(error.status || 400).end(error.message);
  }
};

export default logoutHandler;
```

```js
// api/auth/me.ts
// not api/auth/profile.ts

import { handleProfile } from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0";
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

const profileHandler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  try {
    await handleProfile(req, res);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(error.status || 400).end(error.message);
  }
};

export default profileHandler;
```

```js
// api/auth/signup.ts

import { handleLogin } from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0";
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

const signupHandler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  try {
    await handleLogin(req, res, {
      authorizationParams: {
        screen_hint: "signup",
      },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(error.status || 400).end(error.message);
  }
};

export default signupHandler;
```

Comment: Seems to be a solution for a slightly different problem than the one asked. The question has basePath set, which means the endpoints should be at /my_path/api/auth/* but other code was trying to call /api/auth/*

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue. you can follow this steps:

1. .env file:

```
AUTH0_SECRET='****'
AUTH0_BASE_URL='http://localhost:3000/baseURL/'
AUTH0_ISSUER_BASE_URL='***'
AUTH0_CLIENT_ID='***'
AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET='***'
```

2. _app.tsx file:

```
  <UserProvider profileUrl="/baseURL/api/auth/me">
    <AuthContextProvider>
      <AuthLayout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </AuthLayout>
    </AuthContextProvider>
  </UserProvider>
```

3. /api/auth/[auth0].tsx file:

```
import { handleAuth } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';

export default handleAuth();
```

4. login.tsx file:

```
<Link href="/api/auth/login">
    Sign In with Auth0
</Link>
```

Answer (score -1):

For anyone like me landing here from a random Google search at 2AM:

This problem will appear if you have `.ts`/`.tsx` files inside `/api` folder and you expect your functions to be inside `/pages/api`.
NextJS won't be able to resolve paths properly resulting in 404 responses.